# Best practice in Java for extending abstract class with overriding one method

Tags: java, coding-style

I have an Interface `I1`, one Abstract Class `A1` which implements `I1` and a lot of Classes `C1`...`n` which extend `A1`.

Now, one class `C3` is implementing a special behaviour for a Method `methodA` of `I1`, where every other extending Class of `A1` is implementing a kind of default behaviour.

```
public interface I1 {
  public void methodA();
}
```

---

```
public abstract class A1 implements I1 {
  public void methodA(){
    //default behaviour
  }
  //other methods
}
```

---

```
public class C1 extends A1 {
  //do nothing regarding methodA, because the default behaviour is desired
  //other methods
}
```

---

```
public class C2 extends A1 {
  //do nothing regarding methodA, because the default behaviour is desired
  //other methods
}
```

---

```
public class C3 extends A1 {
  public void methodA(){
    //special behaviour
  }
  //other methods
}
```

---

Now, for me, this does not seem like the best possible solution, since it is difficult to find out, that `C3` is overriding some method from its parent. Is there a best practice for this?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Sorry, that was a simple mistake. If these classes are abstract or not should not be the core of this question. But all Classes C1...3 add some other methods, which i wanted to highlight through the `//other methods` comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would move all common methods in `A1` to another level of abstraction (let's call it `ABase`), and declare in `A1` and `A2` their special behaviors (if any).

This way if more classes of the same type as `C3` are added they don't need to redefine again `methodA`.

```
public interface I1 {
  public void methodA();
}
```

---

```
public abstract class ABase implements I1 {
  //other methods
}
```

---

```
public abstract class A1 extends ABase {
  public void methodA(){
    //default behaviour
  }
}
```

---

```
public abstract class A2 extends ABase {
  public void methodA(){
    //default behaviour
  }
}
```

---

```
public class C1 extends A1 {
  //do nothing regarding methodA, because the default behaviour in A1 is desired
  //other methods
}
```

---

```
public class C2 extends A1 {
  //do nothing regarding methodA, because the default behaviour in A1 is desired
  //other methods
}
```

---

```
public class C3 extends A2 {
  //do nothing regarding methodA, because the default behaviour in A2 is desired
  //other methods
}
```